# Getting 'error while loading shared libraries: invalid ELF header' while running docker-compose up

Tags: node.js, sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I am learning docker containerization. My goal here is to run two containers, one will be node js API and other will be SQL server. I have created image for API part and I am using already existing image for SQL server: `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest`
This is code inside my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      SA_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: myApp:latest
    ports:
      - "3003:3003" #port mapping here.
    environment:
      DB_SERVER: db
      DB_USER: user
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      DB_DATABASE: ShopDB
```

when I run command:
`docker-compose up`

**I am getting this error:**
**/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsss_nss_idmap.so.0: invalid ELF header**

Tried: changing image for sql but did not find any official image other than this.

System specifications:

1. running docker engine on windows 11
2. have SQL server which is Developer Edition (64-bit)
3. have microsoft SQL server 2019

Comment: Are you using WSL2?

Comment: @HansKilian I think not, checked it and only WSL is installed on my win 11.

Comment: `ELF` as mentioned in your error message is the executable file format for Linux programs. That indicates that the image you're trying to run is a Linux image. If you run a straight Windows Docker host without WSL2, you can run Windows images but not Linux images. I tried googling for a Windows based MSSQL image, but I couldn't find one (which surprised me).

Comment: @HansKilian Understood, may be I will try different data base and check if it works or not. other wise there might be some configuration issue. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @HansKilian not surprising (any more) since SQL Server on Windows containers didn't just get deprecated, but was actively removed from image repos, back in 2021. [Update- Beta program for SQL Server on Windows container is suspended.](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/update-beta-program-for-sql-server-on-windows-container-is/ba-p/2516639)

Answer (score 0):

everyone. Resolved this issue by 1st installing WSL2 again and adding this image in docker-compose.yml file:

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU18-ubuntu-20.04
```

Comment: The image you were using originally should also work with WSL2

Comment: @HansKilian yes, I was also hoping for it, but saw this image thought might as well try it. Then pruned all images and again built both containers, and it started working. Now, I am confused on what was root cause of this.